# Reading data with unequal widths in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this dataset and i would like to read it. I still encounter some error. May I know how would i be able to solve them?

```
data ThreeDates; 
infile datalines; 
input Date1 ddmmmyy10. Date2 ddmmyy10. Date ddmmyy9.; 
datalines; 
01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970
05/15/2000   05/15/2002   15May2003
10/10/1998 11/12/2000    25Dec2005
; 
run;
```

Comment: In the future please ensure to show the log as well. Your informats do not match your data, ie ddmmmyy but your data is clearly mmddyy (05/15/2000) 15 in the second column means that has to be the day, not the month.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `:` modifier to read non-standard data. It specifies an informat that the INPUT statement uses to read the variable value. The purpose is to read data values that need the additional instructions that informats can provide but that are not aligned in columns. If data was aligned in columns, you would use `@n` (line pointer controls).

You should also use the `date9.` informat for the `Date` column.

```
data ThreeDates; 
infile datalines;
input Date1 :mmddyy10. Date2 :mmddyy10. Date :date9.; 
format date: mmddyy10.;
datalines; 
01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970
05/15/2000   05/15/2002   15May2003
10/10/1998 11/12/2000    25Dec2005
; 
run;
```

More information about [lists in INPUT Statement](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n0lrz3gb7m9e4rn137op544ddg0v.htm).

PS: Instead of the `:` modifier, you could also use the INFORMAT statement before the INPUT statement:

```
data ThreeDates; 
infile datalines;
informat date1-date2 mmddyy10. date date9.;
input Date1 Date2 Date; 
format date: mmddyy10.;
datalines; 
01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970
05/15/2000   05/15/2002   15May2003
10/10/1998 11/12/2000    25Dec2005
; 
run;
```